# Setting Firebase realtime database rules

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm trying to setup rules for my Firebase realtime database, and I can't figure out why aren't they working. Here is what the top of the data looks like:

[image: Data Structure]

Say I want to allow users to read data where their user name matches the name field in that data. I thought something like this would work

```
{
  "rules": {
    "lauri_laurela" :{
      "$requestid" :{
        ".read" : "data.child('name').val() == auth.token.name",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately that doesnt work for me. I even tried this for the sake of learning

```
{
  "rules": {
    "lauri_laurela" :{
      "$requestid" :{
        ".read" : "data.child('name').exists()",
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or even

```
{
  "rules": {
    "lauri_laurela" :{
      "$requestid" :{
        ".read" : true,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

how ever this does work

```
{
  "rules": {
    "lauri_laurela" :{
       ".read" : true,
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the user UID instead of the name?

Comment: Im planning to make the system more secure later on by making that change Andre. But right now my problem is that I cant even make the rule hirearchy work.

Comment: I would suggest to use the UID right away. Personally I think it's a lot easyer to work with in the security rules and there are a lot more examples using the uid

Comment: Also please include the code you are using to test these rules.

Comment: I added 2 more rule codes in the question. The problem is that for some reason my wildcard token doesnt work, but I need help figuring out why.

Comment: @TinoTerävä the are something wrong with you code. Most probably, you are trying to query `lauri_laurela` branch instead of reading separate requests

Comment: Without seeing the code you are using to test this I don't think anyone can help you.

Comment: Oh you guys are talking about the Java code I wrote my program with? Yeah the problem might be there. If that can be the case, that info already helped me thanks.

Comment: Yes that code. A common problem is the code not matching the rules (I locked the front door (your rules) but I can't open it (You are trying the back door (your code) ) )

Answer (score 0):

auth.token.name only works if name is set. So make sure you have your users have their name saved in their firebase auth profile. You do this using the below code.

```
 FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdates = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
    .setDisplayName("User name")
    .build();

user.updateProfile(profileUpdates)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User profile updated. Now security rules work");
            }
        }
    });
```

To make sure the user has their name saved, you can change your security rules to

```
"auth.token.name!==null && data.child('name').val() == auth.token.name"
```

or

```
"auth.token.name!=="" && data.child('name').val() == auth.token.name"
```

Not sure which one works! hope this will help you.